# Mist wallet password test

Tags: mist, wallets, password

Is there a way to test (if you still know) your Mist wallet password without making a transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Mist is running.

Run this command to attach to the geth daemon:

```
geth attach
```

In the JavaScript console you can try this:

```
personal.unlockAccount('ADDRESS', null, 1)
```

You will be asked for the password.

This command will return true and unlock your account for 1 second if the password is correct.
If it's not you will get an error message:

> Error: could not decrypt key with given passphrase

Comment: I believe the `geth` console also stores a history of your commands, so you'll probably want to clear out the history (I'm not sure how to do that).

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the command. Now you will be asked for the password after you run it.

Answer (score 1):

### It's possible! But it requires using command line tool Geth

Read [Updating an existing account](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#updating-an-existing-account)

You can update an existing account on the command line with the update subcommand with the account address or index as parameter.

```
geth account update b0047c606f3af7392e073ed13253f8f4710b08b6
geth account update 2
```

The account is saved in the newest version in encrypted format, you are prompted for a passphrase to unlock the account and another to save the updated file.

This same command can therefore be used to migrate an account of a deprecated format to the newest format or change the password for an account.

For non-interactive use the passphrase can be specified with the --password flag:

```
geth --password <passwordfile> account new
```

Since only one password can be given, only format update can be performed, changing your password is only possible interactively.

**Note:** Account update has the a side effect that the order of your accounts changes.

After a successful update, all previous formats/versions of that same key will be removed!

Comment: Thanks for the answer niksmac, but unfortunately I'm not competent in command line. Is it not possible to make a 'transaction' that you know will be rejected or something? Or will you then still lose the paid gass?